# Finding the Minimum Number of Objects Required to Create a Certain Sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

You have N fields (1 <= N <= 100) that are all arranged in a line along a long
straight road.  Each field might contain several types of music players; You own
B types of music players (1 <= B <= 20), and a music player of type i gives a volume of
V(i) (1 <= V(i) <= 100).  Moreover, there is a strong wind blowing down the
road, which carries the sound of music in one direction: if the volume of
music in some field is X, then in the next field this will contribute X-1
to the total music volume (and X-2 in the field after that, etc.). But, the volume being contributed once it hits 0 will not become negative.

Given the volume of music that you records in each field, please compute
the minimum possible number of music players you might own.

The volume you records in any field is at most 100,000.

INPUT FORMAT:

- Line 1: The integers N and B.
- Lines 2..1+B: Line i+1 contains the integer V(i).
- Lines 2+B..1+B+N: Line 1+B+i contains the total volume of all mooing
      in field i.

SAMPLE INPUT:

5 2
5
7
0
17
16
20
19

INPUT DETAILS:
You owns 5 fields, with volumes recorded at 0,17,16,20,19.  There are two types
of music players; the first has a volume of 5, and the other has a volume of 7.

OUTPUT FORMAT:

- Line 1: The minimum number of music players you own, or -1 if there is no
      configuration of music players consistent with the input.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

4

OUTPUT DETAILS:

There are 2 music players of type #1 and 1 music player of type #2 in field 2, and there is
another music player of type#1 in field 4 giving a total of 4 music players. This is the minimum needed to give those volumes recorded in the field.

My Ideas:
I understand that this is a dynamic programming problem. I was thinking that dp[i] represents the nth field's music players up to that point, but i can't seem to figure this out.

Could you please aid me in explaining a nice dp solution and if possible provide some psuedocode so I can get better at coding dp.

Comment: This seems similar to (but not completely isomorphic with) a move generator and evaluator for Mancala [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala] games.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but a solution to solve the problem in time complexity `O(B * MAX(recorded volume) + N)` using dynamic programming

It is a two-step solution.
In step 1, find the minimum music players required to produce the specific volume from 1 to MAX(recorded volume) (maybe some volumes are not available)

Then in step 2, from the first field to the last field, calculate the volume needs to be produced on each field, then use the result in step 1 to know how many music players needs in the field.

Use your input/output as example.
In step 1, you can get player_required[5] = 1, player_required[7] = 1, player_required[10] = 2, player_required[12] = 2, player_required[14] = 2, player_required[15] = 3, player_required[17] = 3, player_required[19] = 3, ... . Means that you need one player to produce volume of 5 or volume of 7, but if you want to produce volume of 15 or volume of 17, you needs 3 players.

In step 2, go to field 1 first, the volume is 0 and no players is required. In field 2, the volume is 17, so you need 3 players in this field. In field 3, the volume from field 2 is 16 (17-1) and it matches the volume in field 3. Therefore, no players is required in field 3. Then in field 4, the volume from field 3 is 15 but the volume is 20 in the field. So you know you should produces volume of 5 in field 4. According to the computation in step 1, you need 1 player here. And field 5 does not need any player in. To sum up, you need 4 music players (3 in field 2 and 1 in field 4)

If there is no way to produce the required volume in any field in step 2, you should output -1 since there is no configuration of music players consistent with the input.

Sorry for the poor English and hope it helps.